# Prove that the equation $x^{x}+y^{y}+z^{z}=t^{t}$ has no solution over the positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove that the  equation

$$x^{x}+y^{y}+z^{z}=t^{t}$$

has no solution over the positive integers.

Comment: I almost wanted to give a hint, but if you look at this the right way it is very easy. What have you tried?

Comment: @MarkBennet: Enlighten me.

Comment: I do not actually understand why the vote to close.I have seen upvotes for much more easy and sometimes almost-duplicate questions.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas It happens... too many people here a bit harsh.

Comment: @Lucian See DanielV's answer below. For $n\ge 2$ it is trivial that $(n+1)^{n+1}= (n+1)\cdot (n+1)^{n}\gt 3\cdot n^n$ and there is very little more to check. But OP should show their own work and thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme of proof:

Sort $x,y,z$: $x\le y \le z$.

Obviously, that $t>z$.

So $t\ge z+1$. Then

$$t^t-z^z \ge (z+1)^{z+1}-z^z \\ =[by ~binomial ~formula] \\ = \Bigl(z^{z+1}+(z+1)z^z+\ldots+(z+1)z+1\Bigr)-z^z>2z^{z+1},$$
but must be
$$
x^x+y^y\le 2 z^z.
$$

So,
$$
x^x+y^y<t^t-z^z.
$$

---

For intuition:
the set $\{n^n\} = \{1,4,27,256,3125, 46656, ...\}$ is very "sparse" to get nice identities like $x^x+y^y+z^z=t^t$.

Answer (score 6):

For sufficiently large $n$, $\quad 3n^n < (n+1)^{n+1}$

Comment: IMHO this shows that the number of solutions is finite, but not that there are none.

Comment: @gammatester: I am willing to believe that Daniel is being rather tongue-in-cheek when he said "sufficiently large". Observe that $(n+1)^{n+1} / n^n > n+1$ so the inequality holds for $n \geq 2$ directly. The case $n =1$ can be checked separately by hand.

Comment: @Willie Wong: This is convincing, and I learned the new term *tongue-in-cheek*

Answer (score 2):

Let $z \leq y \leq x$.

---

Firstly, we show that $z$ is not equal to $t$.

By contradiction, let $z=t$. $x ^ 3+y^3=0$, thus $x = y = 0$

However, 0 is not a natural number and therefore, $z \not= t$

---

Secondly, we show that $z$ cannot be 1 less than $t$.

I will show this by showing that $x^x+y^y+z^z<t^t$

Let x, y and z be the largest possible number, which would be $t-1$

$x^x+y^y+z^z=3 \times (t-1)^{(t-1)}$ which has to be equal to or more than $t^t$ for there to have a solution.

Looking at the small values, we see that there can be no such $t$.

For instance, if $t=2$, $3 \times (t-1)^{(t-1)}=3$ but $t^t=4$

$t=3$, $3 \times (t-1)^{(t-1)}=12$ but $t^t=27$

$t=4$, $3 \times (t-1)^{(t-1)}=81$ but $t^t=256$

Therefore, $3 \times (t-1)^{(t-1)}>t^t$ and $x^x+y^y+z^z<t^t$.

---

Thus, $x^x+y^y+z^z=t^t$ has no solution over the natural numbers.